# MyProfile matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

It's occuring like this; 
DoesNotExist at /post/naver/

I'm getting this error now that I had added id at the end in this line,  `profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)`
 I'm using userena. I have to use id, otherwise it gives  not 'SimpleLazyObject'

This is the traceback

```
Traceback:
/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
/ebagu/main/views.py" in post
  87.       profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  127.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  334.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /post/naver/
Exception Value: MyProfile matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Did you print request.user may be it is showing "Anonymous User"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the profile is not guaranteed to exist in the database, you will need to write code to handle that case. A common approach is to catch the `DoesNotExist` exception.

```
try:
    profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    # if it's a OneToOne field, you can do:
    # profile = request.user.myprofile
except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:
    profile = None
    # other code that handles missing profile
```

If all logged in users have a profile, but your view is also handling anonymous users, your code might be clearer if you use an if statement instead. You can instantiate a profile that displays default values for anonymous users.

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    profile = request.user.myprofile
else:
    profile = MyProfile(favourite_food="pasta", favourite_colour="blue")
```

Comment: Is there a way to show profile for non-logged in user as well? I'm using this for ppl who are not logged in. and I had to ad id at the end of request.user

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example to handle anonymous users, but I'm not sure if it's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use

```
profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
```

Comment: or just `user=request.user`

Comment: Are you sure that the `MyProfile` object exists?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that user is exist in Model (MyProfile)

```
profile = None
if MyProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
    profile = MyProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
else:
    pass
    # Do something if data not exist's
```

Comment: A better option might be `try:`, `get()`, `except MyProfile.DoesNotExist:`, which avoids the extra query for `exists()`.

Comment: @Alasdair can you show me the solution with try and except?, I tried it but won't work...

Comment: with this solution and I put request.user.id instead of just request.user, I get local variable 'profile' referenced before assignment

Comment: I've added an answer using try..except below.

Comment: Is there a way to show profile for non-logged in user as well? I'm using this for ppl who are not logged in. and I had to ad id at the end of request.user

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming based off other questions that `MyProfile` is a one to one field on your user. so you can just access it via

```
 request.user.myprofile
```